# Modifying how nHibernate saves Saga data in nServiceBus

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nservicebus, hbm

I'm having an issue where I'm sending a message to nServiceBus with a message data field of variable length.  nServiceBus is using nHibernate to create a table called

```
[NServiceBus].[PendingMentorEmailSagaData]
```

from a class called PendingMentorEmailSagaData . The message field is however getting set to nvarchar(255), I am looking for a way to have it set to nvarchar(MAX).

I've tried using an embedded hbm file, but am getting a "`persistent class PendingMentorEmailSagaData not found`" error.

This probably means I can't figure out what class to set the file too.

The hbm file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
      <class name="PendingMentorEmailSagaData">
        <id name="Id" />
        <property name="OriginalMessageId" />
        <property name="Originator" />
        <property name="PendingMentorEmailCommandId" />
        <property name="JobBoardCode" />
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

PendingMentorEmailSagaData is the name of the saga's data class.

Comment: My question simplified is how do you override nservicebus's nhibernate functionality in the way it creates its tables in its exportschema.  I've tried adding assembly & namespace with no luck either.  The assembly would be the project name & the namespace would be the namespace to the data class right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a PendingMentorEmailSagaData.hbm.xml file in the same project that the saga exists on, eg:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
      <class name="MY_NAMESPACE.PendingMentorEmailSagaData, MY_ASSEMBLY_NAME" table="PendingMentorEmailSagaData" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="all">
        <id name="Id" type="Guid">
          <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="Originator" />
        <property name="OriginalMessageId" />
        <property name="LargeText" type="StringClob" />
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

2. Mark that file as an Embedded Resource

Comment: makes sense, including more information on where to find the class should fix it, however I decided to switch gears and go w the fluentnhibernate approach which turned out about 100x easier to work on.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I would be interested to find out more about how you managed to use fluentnhibernate with NServiceBus ?

Comment: Well, we tried to inherit the class's classmap kind of how the hbm file is read by nhibernate based on its functionality.  However, didn't get that working either, implemented a workaround where the message data is not persisted to the saga but called when the message needs to be sent.  This works only because I only need to send the latest message thus the data in the db is most current, but next time I run into this I'm going to try and implement a classmap, or an hbm file so as to not do a workaround.